# Adding LSTM layers in Keras produces input error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

First of all apologies if I word this wrong, I'm relatively new to TensorFlow

I am designing a model for simple classification of a dataset, each column is an attribute and the final column is the class. I split these and generate a dataframe in the usual way.

If I generated a model with dense layers, it works great:

```
def baseline_model():
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=len(dataframe.columns)-2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(20,activation='sigmoid'))   
model.add(Dense(unique, activation='softmax'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
return model
```

If I were to add, say, an LSTM layer to the model:

```
def baseline_model():
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=len(dataframe.columns)-2, activation='sigmoid'))


#this bit here >
model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(20,activation='sigmoid'))   
model.add(Dense(unique, activation='softmax'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
return model
```

I get the following error when I execute the code:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

I'm not sure where these variables are coming from although, maybe it's the classes? I have three classes of data ('POSITIVE', 'NEGATIVE', 'NEUTRAL') mapped to sets of well over 2,000 attribute values - they're statistical extractions of timewindowed EEG brainwave data from multiple electrodes classed by emotional state.

Note:
The *'input_dim=len(dataframe.columns)-2'* produces the number of attributes (inputs), I do this as I'd like the script to work with CSV datasets of different sizes on the fly

Also, there are no tabs in my code pasted but it is indented and will compile

The full code is pasted here: https://pastebin.com/1aXp9uDA for presentation purposes. Apologies in advance for the terrible practices! This is just an initial project, I do plan on cleaning it all up later on!

Answer (score 1):

In your original code you have an input dimension of 2 which is shaped (batch, feature).  When you add an LSTM, you're telling Keras you want to do the classification given the last N timesteps, hence you need an input that is shaped (batch, timestep, feature).  It's easy to think that an LSTM will look back across all inputs in the batch but unfortunately it doesn't.  You have to manually organize your data to present all the timestep elements together.

To split up your data you generally do a sliding window of length N (where N is how many values you wish the LSTM to look back across).  You can slide the window N steps each time, meaning there's no overlap of the data or you can simply slide it one sample, meaning you get multiple copies of your data.  There are numerous blogs on how to do this.  Take a look at this one [How to Reshape Input Data for LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/).

You also have one other issue.  For your LSTM, you probably want "return_sequences=False".  With this equal to True, you would need to have an output "Y" value for each element of your timestep.  You probably want your "Y" value to represent the next value in your time-series.  Keep this in mind when organizing your data.

The above link provides some nice examples or you can search for more in-depth ones.  If you follow those it should be clear how to reorganize things for an LSTM.